# Is is possible to skip the confirmation step while adding a repository?

Tags: repository, add-apt-repository

When I add a repository by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

It outputs this dialog:

```
Updated versions of X.org drivers, libraries, etc. for Ubuntu.

This PPA is for stable upstream releases of X.org components.  If you're looking for something even more bleeding-edge, please see the xorg-edgers PPA.

While Ubuntu does not "officially/formally" support these packages, if you discover problems when installing these debs please feel free to report bugs to launchpad.  However, please make sure to clearly state that you are running packages from this PPA so we know the fixes need to come here.

If you are upgrading from one release to another with this PPA activated, please install the ppa-purge package and use it to downgrade everything in here beforehand. sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates will do it.

[Directions for packaging drivers can be seen at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/DriverBuilding]
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
```

I want to skip the confirmation step  `Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it`

How can I automatically confirm the addition of a PPA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Adding `-y` on the above command assumes yes for all the prompts, so it won't ask you to `Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it`.